Need 1 row returned based on most-recent date, OnBase document cleanup
I am trying to cleanup an application's reports and archived reports.  Hyland's OnBase is our archiving solution. I am trying to determine the most-recent date on which any ItemNum was viewed. Determining the most-recent date that a report type was viewed can help me determine if any of these 400+ reports are useful, or if they can be disabled.
Some important columns:

ItemTypeGroupNum - The application's report section in Onbase
ItemTypeNum - Correlates to type of report coming out of our application
ItemNum - A individual timestamped report

Example:

ItemTypeGroupNum = 161 - The application's block of reports within OnBase
ItemTypeNum = 5681 -     Report group title = G/L File Maintenance
ItemNum = 250727772 - G/L File Maintenance - 6/25/2024

My 1st attempt and the resulting replies to review a similar, albeit different post here.
Next came attempts to use partition by and over. My SQL skills aren't that sharp so this is possibly due to user error.
Next came an attempt to use outer apply and that did not succeed, I referenced this post.
My most recent attempt:
SELECT
    dt.itemtypenum, 
    dt.itemtypename,
    tlx.MaxLogDate
FROM 
    hsi.itemdata AS id
INNER JOIN 
    hsi.doctype AS dt ON dt.itemtypenum = id.itemtypenum   /* do I need this join?  */
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT
         tl.num, MAX(tl.logdate) AS MaxLogDate
     FROM 
         hsi.transactionxlog AS tl
     WHERE
         tl.num = id.itemnum
         -- AND tl.itemnum = 1234
         AND tl.action IN (32, 35)       /* showing only 'view' actions  */
         -- AND tl.logdate >= '2023-06-25'   
     GROUP BY
         tl.logdate, tl.num) tlx

The results I am getting are including multiple rows for the same ItemTypeNum but different ItemNum, with the most-recent accessed date for that individual ItemNum:



ItemTypeNum
ItemName
MaxLogDate




5257
Report Title 1 - 01/01/2024
01/02/2024


5257
Report Title 1 - 05/16/2024
06/11/2024


5681
G/L File Maintenance - 04/20/2024
05/15/2024


5681
G/L File Maintenance - 03/08/2024
06/01/2024


5370
Exception Report - 02/20/2024
NULL



What I am wanting to have returned would be only the 2nd, 4th, and 5th rows from the above table, the rows that have the max date for that group of ItemTypeNum:



ItemTypeNum
ItemName
MaxLogDate




5257
Report Title 1 - 05/16/2024
06/11/2024


5681
G/L File Maintenance - 03/08/2024
06/01/2024


5370
Exception Report - 02/20/2024
NULL



OnBase database diagram

Seems, instead of  group by tl.logdate, tl.num better group by tl.num.

@ValNik that produced results similar to the example I posted.  :(

I don't currently have access to an OnBase system, so I can't test this solution. But if you want the bottom results from your query, this ought to do it:
SELECT
    dt.itemtypenum 'Doc type code', 
    dt.itemtypename 'Document type',
    MAX(tl.logdate) 'Most Recent Access'
FROM hsi.itemdata AS id
INNER JOIN hsi.doctype AS dt ON dt.itemtypenum = id.itemtypenum
LEFT JOIN hsi.transactionxlog AS tl ON tl.itemtypenum = id.itemtypenum
WHERE tl.action IN (32, 35)
    AND tl.logdate >= '2023-06-25' -- Replace this as appropriate; could be lots of records
GROUP BY dt.itemnum, dt.itemtypenum

I seem to recall that num and itemnum are identical in transactionxlog, and num is indexed. You may want to double-check that on your system to speed your query, and adjust as necessary.
Yes, you do need the join to the doctype table, unless the doc type num is recorded in transactionxlog, which I think it isn't.

This seems to return the last time the document was accessed for me.
SELECT
    id.itemnum 'Doc Id', 
    dt.itemtypename 'Document type',
    MAX(tl.logdate) 'Most Recent Access'
FROM 
    hsi.itemdata AS id
        INNER JOIN hsi.doctype AS dt ON dt.itemtypenum = id.itemtypenum
            LEFT JOIN hsi.transactionxlog AS tl ON tl.itemnum = id.itemnum
WHERE 
    tl.action IN (32, 35)
GROUP BY 
    id.itemnum, dt.itemtypename, dt.itemtypenum
ORDER BY 3

Is the document type relevant if you just want to determine the last time a document was accessed? If not, you can use the simpler:
SELECT
    id.itemnum 'Doc Id', 
    id.itemname 'Document Name',
    MAX(tl.logdate) 'Most Recent Access'
FROM 
    hsi.itemdata AS id
        LEFT JOIN hsi.transactionxlog AS tl ON tl.itemnum = id.itemnum
WHERE 
    tl.action IN (32, 35)
GROUP BY 
    id.itemnum, id.itemname
ORDER BY 3

which shows the document name instead of the type.
